# CSS text and box shadows causing scrollbar to appear?

Tags: html5-canvas, css

I've been struggling with this one.

I'm creating a personal website, and I'm using an animated canvas element for the background (animated via jquery). The issue seems to be that the text and box shadows for my anchor tags on hover are causing my canvas element to show a vertical scroll bar, and it is only happening in Chrome.

If I remove the text & box shadows, or if I remove the canvas elements then the issue goes away. I've tried adding overflow:hidden to pretty much everything, but to no avail.

See my website here: http://www.trunker.me

```
#mainMenu a:hover , #mainMenu a:active {
    color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(255,0,0,1);
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(255,0,0,1);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Using windows 7 ultimate with Chrome Version 36.0.1985.125 m. It creates a second vertical scroll bar next to the browser scroll bar. Screenshot here:[screenshot http://www.trunker.me/images/Capture.PNG](http://www.trunker.me/images/Capture.PNG)

Comment: Which OS and Chrome version are you using at the moment? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Thanks Alex. Updated with the info and screenshot.

Comment: On iOS X it does not happen. I tried to load up a VM with the same OS and Chrome and I don't see the issue. Let me investigate more...

Comment: I noticed you have applied overflow:scroll on several elements, why is that?

Comment: hmm, you must be referring to the boilerplate.css? I haven't explicitly done that anywhere that I'm aware of.

Comment: yes, you should remove those :) try to override it on the console to see what happens

Comment: Alex, I think you just solved my problem. I modified the boilerplate.css to remove the overflow scroll, and the issue seems to be resolved.

Comment: Great I rewrote that as answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove all those `overflow:scroll` from several elements in your code. 
Try overriding them directly in the console.

Comment: gah, I was struggling with that for a while! Didn't think to check the boilerplate. Thanks!!!

Comment: No prob Mike, glad to help :) I suggest you to debug always using the browser console and also check the computed css properties including the inherited ones :)